# Maximum Limit for Items in In App Billing / In-App Purchase

Tags: android, iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I would like to know what the maximum number of items that can be placed in In App billing for both Android and iphone. I seem to remember reading around 3000 but I cannot find the reference.

Also if 3000 is the maximum what are the legitimate way to get around this. My app will sell content and I thought a possible way around the problem would be to have a central app that shows the content, then a number of different libraries where you can purchase the content. Would that be a viable work around?

Comment: Would it be feasible to sell just the one product, "MyCompanyCredits", and use these credits to purchase your in-app content? This has the advantage that you don't have to create more than 3000 products on iTunesConnect!

Comment: Good idea, something I will consider but I am not sure users would like it too much. It seems ok in games but could be a little tricky for what i am selling

Comment: While it's true I got the idea from games, companies such as Facebook use Facebook credits for selling things in a more professional environment, the concept certainly wouldn't be lost on your users.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only answer the Apple part of your question. I just spoke with them 2 weeks ago, because I also have a lot of items that can be purchased in my app.

The current limit for Apple's In-Purchase is 10.000 items. If that is not enough you can be granted an additional 10.000 items by Apple.

You can try to have one central app that displays content and then several library apps that sell the content. However I'm not sure if Apple will allow that. You should clarify that before implementing it.

Another possibility would be to set up your own shop and sell the content there. The big advantage would be that you wouldn't have to pay the 30% share to Apple. The disadvantage is that you have to set up the shop yourself and that Apple does not allow direct links from within your app to you shop.

Comment: Do you know how to get the additional 10.000 items from apple ?

Comment: You have to contact them and ask them. There is to automated way to do that.

Comment: @joern to add more to your answer, 1oooo items for each app but you can only configure looo items for single upload of your app. please refer app metadata specification document.

Comment: What do you mean with "only 1000 items for single upload"?

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the [Requirements and Limitations](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#billing-limitations) section of the developer guide there does not appear to be a specified limit.

The [In-App Billing Availability and Policies](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1153481) section of the Google Play Help Centre is also lacking any information.

You should raise this directly with the support team for Google play at the support contact page for [Google Play Developers: Publishers & Merchants](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?answer=136601&hl=en) and ask them to update the information on their website.

Answer (score 2):

limit of GoolePlayStore BillingItem is 1000!

I actually tried^^！！

Comment: Me too, getting an error after 1000, not sure if there's a way around (for Apple you can just ask up to 10'000)

Comment: We’re you able to get past the 1,000 limit on google? Just ran into this. Stopping further development of my project.

Comment: So far there seems to be no remedy....
As I remember at the time, I asked Google if they could extend it specially for me, and they said no.
Apple's cap on the number of items charged is about 10 times higher.

I had no choice but to create tickets and internal concepts to group items of the same price.