# In app purchase maximum limit

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I heard that apple is newly offer additional 10,000 items for the in app purchase products (Beside the original 10,000 items) .. if that is correct how can I achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: where did you get this information from? the offical documentation doesn't mention it in a word http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @relikd check the correct answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391473/maximum-limit-for-items-in-in-app-billing-in-app-purchase) please.

Comment: ok then I think you should simply call them and ask for that. seems like the other one did that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Login to [itunes connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com). In the bottom panel, click contact us.
In resulting dropdown, select 'Manage your in app purchases'.
In second dropdown, select 'Eligible for in app purchase'.

This will open a section with relavent links in apple documentation.
If this does not answer it, there will be one more 'Contact us' link which will directly take you to a question form that will be submitted directly to Apple customer care. That should be your final place for the answer.

Comment: Just for curiosity, what is the kind of products you are aiming here that requires such huge quantity? I believe Apple bans sale of consumer goods from its store.

Comment: ok nirav you are lucky there is no answer to earn it the bounty except you , but actually 3 days before I ask this question I did what you say :)

Comment: Thanks for the bounty (and I had no way of knowing if you had already followed my solution, or it wouldn't be considered an answer technically :-)) In any case I would be happier if this could lead you to a solution. Yes?