# Creating more than 1000 IAPs for an application

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, itunes, newsstand-kit

I am working over application which sells product (similar to newsstand) to user. There is limit from apple on number of IAPs that can be created inside app. Right now limit is 1000. But my app requirement is more than 1000 IAP. Is there any way i can have this increased?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In app purchase maximum limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440049/in-app-purchase-maximum-limit)