# Maximum number of in-app items

Tags: google-chrome, web, in-app

Chrome Web Apps - what is the maximum number of in-app items that can be listed on the Chrome Web Store?  The only thing I've seen is 100 Total items, not sure if this includes add-ins.  For Apple, looks like 10,000 (if not 20,000).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming issue.

Comment: It's like this question, but different platform.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391473/maximum-limit-for-items-in-in-app-billing-in-app-purchase

Comment: Thank you. I marked that as off topic, too. But that was from four years ago and the rules have changed or tightened up. SO is for programming questions and this is not a programming question.